# Load a html or div's content into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of "li". On clicking each of those "li", I'd like to load a "div" with contents from a html page. I've read some answers on stackoverflow & tried them but they aren't helping me get this working.

Here's the code am trying now

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
   <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#page1").click(function(){
            $('#result').load('dst.html');
           //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
         }); 

         $("#page2").click(function(){
            $('#result').load('incf.html');
           //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
         });
       });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header class="site-header-wrap">
         <div class="site-header">
            <h1>MY TOOL</h1>
         </div>
      </header>
      <div id='cssmenu'>
         <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>HOME</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="page1" href="#"><span>OPTION 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="page2" href="#"><span>OPTION 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="page3" href="#"><span>OPTION 3</span></a></li>  
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="result"></div>
   </body>
<html>
```

The code in dst.html is

```
<html lang=''>
   <body>
      <p> In page 1(dst page) </p>
   </body>
<html>
```

Could I request help please spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: please check for any path errors ,other errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working for the most part for me the only thing i changed in your code is `$('#dblock').load('dst.html');` to `$('#result').load('dst.html');` since there is no div with the id `#dblock`

also make sure your file structure is setup properly and the html files are there with what you have setup now you should have three html files in the same folder

Comment: Hello NooBskie - All good now. Thank you heaps & tons. The problem is with Chrome!!!! It's working on firefox. I've been working primarily with Chrome for months now. So, it didn't strike me that this may be a browser issue.